# git - Filename renamed unexpectedly when merged

Tags: git

I'm finished with `origin/feature/a` so delete it, add another branch named `b` so I have `origin/feature/b`. After a while I got that I should edit something in `origin/feature/a` but I have deleted it. So I rename the `b` to `a`. Commit. Push. My colleague pull and merge the changes from `a`. Finally some filenames are renamed unexpectedly. The file `test.php` has changed to `test.php-origin/feature/a` and the file `test.vue` has changed to `test.vue-origin/feature/a` and the main file is deleted.

Why this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Post commands that you issued and the response of the commands.

Comment: me: `git commit -m "done!"` `git push` he: `git pull` => `index.php` renamed to `index.php-origin/feature/a`

Comment: These commands do not explain the behavior. What were the commands used to delete and re-create the branches on your side?

Comment: Could it be that the files are renamed by a merge tool at the "he" side? Did "he" check, that `git diff HEAD~ HEAD` indeed shows that the files were renamed? (I am assuming `HEAD` is the merge commit.)

Comment: In my side because of using PHPStorm, I just checkout and rename the branches easily in bottom right of its window. And of course in he side, he doesn't see any specific difference in branch names.

Comment: If you are not using the standard Git toolset, I cannot help; sorry.